# How does normalization of samples make the contour line of parameter be ball?

Tags: machine-learning

I saw many references explain normalization accelerating gradient descent by comparing the ball distribution and ellipse distribution, which makes sense. However I want to understand how normalization of samples makes the contour line of parameter be ball?

I saw [How does having different scales on features make an elliptical contour plot?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/465957/how-does-having-different-scales-on-features-make-an-elliptical-contour-plot) gives a explicit example that ball contour line is faster than ellipse. Could you use similar example to illustrate that normalization of samples makes the contour line of parameter be ball?

I understand as if parameter is $(,)$ and sample variable $=(^1,^2).$ Then for a loss function $(^1,^2,,),$ $^1,^2$ having the same variance and mean induces $_{^1,^2}(,)$ having a ball contour line? I guess the analysis is base on such loss function $=^1+^2,$ each component of parameter homogenously depends on each component of sample. For the more complicate loss function, how can we get the similar conclusion?

Comment: Normalisation doesn't make it a ball. it just makes the coordinates (=variables) have same variance. other directions (eg x1 + x2) will not have the same variance.  a ball has same variance in all directions. you need to do principal components to actually make it a ball.

Comment: @seanv507 could you give more details? I mean the contour line of parameter be ball.

Comment: Am I understand correctly? if parameter is $(a,b)$ and sample variable $x=(x^1,x^2).$ Then for a loss function $f(x^1,x^2,a,b),$ $x^1,x^2$ having the same variance and mean induces $f_{x^1,x^2}(a,b)$ having a ball contour line? I guess the analysis is base on such loss function $f = x^1a+x^2b,$ each component of parameter homogenously depends on each component of sample. For the more complicate loss function, how can we get the similar conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

The variance and normalisation depend on the the type of problem.

The simplest example is linear regression

$E = \sum_{j=1}^{j=N}(y_j-a x_{1j} - b x_{2j})^2$

to simplify further we drop $y_j$, ie our target is simply to output zero always
then
$E = a^2\sum_{j=1}^{j=N} x_{1j}^2 -2ab \sum_{j=1}^{j=N} x_{1j}x_{2j} +  b^2 \sum_{j=1}^{j=N} x_{2j}^2 $

the contour lines are the points $(a,b)$ that have same E.

these points are the equations for an ellipse, because they have the form
$c_1 x^2 + c_2 xy + c_3y^2 = c_4$ for constants $c_1,...c_4$

simplifying the problem further we assume $x_1, x_2$ have mean zero, then the equation becomes

$E = a^2 \sigma_{1}^2 -2ab \rho \sigma_{1}\sigma_{2} +  b^2 \sigma_{2}^2 $

so if variance is same *and* correlation is zero, then the contour line is a circle.

you should be able to work through what happens also when means are non zero.

This analysis could be extended by eg performing a Taylor expansion (to second order) of a more complicated loss function

Comment: I get your point. I mean the "circle contour" is a very approximate naming for a general  complicate lose function. But normalization makes contour large probability to be close circle, right?